# The IE Fieldset Background Color Bleed Bug

Tags: html, css

**Setup:**

> I have an HTML page with a fieldset
>   element. The background color of the
>   fieldset element is different from the
>   background of the page. The border of
>   the fieldset has a slightly darker
>   color that the background.

**Problem:**

> In Firefox only the area inside the
>   border has the specified background
>   color. In IE7 the background color
>   flows over the area delimited by the
>   border (only at the top).

**Question:**

> What can I do to make the background
>   of the fieldset element stay within
>   the area delimited by the border on
>   IE7?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

see this article for how to fix this problem:

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=DD9F3

**In summary:**
"
Since IE's problem seems to extend from the fact that the legend is a child of the fieldset, the way to fix the bug is to disassociate the legend with the fieldset. The legend element has to stay nested within the fieldset element, of course, for the (X)HTML to remain valid, but if we absolutely position it, it will be removed from the flow of the document and treated by elements outside of it — including its parent — as if it didn't exist.
"

Comment: Nice, however the [solution posted by Jonathan](http://www.mattheerema.com/web-design/2006/04/getting-fieldset-backgrounds-and-legends-to-behave-in-ie/) is maybe more brief and synoptical than the above link.

Answer (score 10):

<s>Have you reset your margins and padding?</s>

**EDIT:**

Actually, Matt Heerema apparently had a similar problem. Which he [successfully fixed](http://www.mattheerema.com/web-design/2006/04/getting-fieldset-backgrounds-and-legends-to-behave-in-ie/).

"[Getting Fieldset Backgrounds and Legends to Behave in IE](http://www.mattheerema.com/web-design/2006/04/getting-fieldset-backgrounds-and-legends-to-behave-in-ie/)".

Comment: Yes, the margins and padding have been set.

Comment: @Diego, Check out the link I provided in my EDIT. I think you will find it to be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem and an easy fix was to wrap the fieldset into a `div` and set the color of the background for that div instead of setting it to the fieldset tag.